# App turning my WiFi on?

Tags: wi-fi, battery, whatsapp-messenger

Due to the time it happens, I'm highly suspicious about WhatsApp and the Drive upload function.

I put my phone in Airplane mode before going to sleep, and this is what I see the day after.

Note that my WiFi appears as OFF when I wake up, yet the phone indicates it has been turned on for the whole night...

[image: Battery graph and proof it turns on "ghostly"]
<sup>Battery graph and proof it turns on "ghostly" (click to enlarge)</sup>

The Drive backup starts uploading in the morning when I turn WiFi on. But I think it's around 2 AM where you see my WiFi turning on (after WhatsApp backup?)

Comment: What's your exact question on this then? What do you want to know exactly?

Answer (score 0):

On your screenshot, you have Wi-Fi enabled, even though you have airplane mode on

If that isn't the cause of your problem, background Wi-Fi scanning might be the cause
You can turn it off by going to Wi-Fi -> Advanced -> Scanning always available 
Or for >=6.0 Android versions, it's Location -> Scanning
That feature enables Wi-Fi even if you disable it